# Records greater than epoch timestamp using only LIKE operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, json, like, date-math

I have the following query so far and unfortunately, I cannot use *regexp* or *greater than* operators, I can only use the `LIKE` keyword.

The whole column is in a json string, I can't use `json_value` or regexp because I'm on SQL Server so I'm stuck with using `LIKE`. It's SQL Server 2014 and `json_value` is not supported until 2016.

```
SELECT * FROM DataTableOne 
WHERE update_date LIKE '%1645290000%'
```

I would like to retrieve all records where the epoch unix timestamp is greater than 1645290000 using only the SQL `LIKE` keyword (or even between 1645290000 and 9999999999 using the SQL `LIKE` operator).

Any help will be much appreciated since this is a very tough unique case where I am limited to using only the `LIKE` keyword.

Sample table/data below:

```
CREATE TABLE DataTableOne (
    ID int,
    DATA varchar(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO DataTableOne (ID, DATA)
VALUES (1, '{"name":"Cole", "update_date":"2855290000"}'),
(2, '{"name":"Peter", "update_date":"1222290000"}') ;
```

There could be a thousand rows with this sort of data and the only ones I want are the ones where the update_date is greater than 1645290000.

Running the query on the above table I gave should only return the first row since the *update_date* of 2855290000 is indeed greater than 1645290000 numerically.

Comment: Its in a json string, I posted the schema/sample data in table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realistically, you shouldn't be directly working on JSON data in versions of SQL Server without explicit JSON support. Ideally, the JSON source would be transformed to a relational format during import. Querying the data then becomes easy.

That said, if you *really must* do as you say, there are a number of options.

One is to convert the (simple) JSON to XML, then use XQuery:

```
SELECT
    DTO.*
FROM dbo.DataTableOne AS DTO
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT 
        TRY_CONVERT(xml,
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(DTO.[DATA], 
                            '"name":', 'name='),
                        ', "update_date":', ' update_date='),
                    '{', '<r '),
                '}', '/>'))
) AS X (x)
WHERE
    1 = X.x.exist('r[1][@update_date ge 1645290000]');
```

The `[1]` isn't necessary there, but produces a slightly nicer execution plan in the case there is only one *update_date* per row.

It is also just about possible to use `LIKE` exclusively, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.DataTableOne AS DTO
WHERE 
    DTO.[DATA] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 
        LIKE '%"update_date":"164529[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"%'
    OR DTO.[DATA] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 
        LIKE '%"update_date":"1645[3-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"%'
    OR DTO.[DATA] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 
        LIKE '%"update_date":"164[6-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"%'
    OR DTO.[DATA] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 
        LIKE '%"update_date":"16[5-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"%'
    OR DTO.[DATA] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 
        LIKE '%"update_date":"1[7-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"%'
    OR DTO.[DATA] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 
        LIKE '%"update_date":"[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"%';
```

[*db<>fiddle* online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=7fbfbe46cd94453326baea0f418951f1)

If you understand the `LIKE` logic there you will be able to generalise it for other values. That should get you started if you're trying to solve a puzzle or set question of some kind.

Answer (score 9):

I believe it is best to separate the problem into two parts, locate the update_date and then use ">" to filter:

```
select * from DataTableOne
where cast ( substring( data
           , charindex('"update_date":', data)+15
           , len(data)- (charindex('"update_date":', data)+15) -1 )
      as bigint ) > 1645290000
```

Note that if there are malformed JSON in your table the query will fail. If that is the case you may want to encapsulate the extraction in a function / procedure with error handling.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f825a3068f83bc1ee83d686c363814c9)

Or, since `TRY_CAST` is implemented in SQL Server 2014, if the cast fails, null is returned which never satisfies `>`, so we can simply do:

```
select * from DataTableOne
where TRY_CAST ( substring( data
           , charindex('"update_date":', data)+15
           , len(data)- (charindex('"update_date":', data)+15) -1 )
         as bigint ) > 1645290000;
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=42b1ba73f768f599fef84047e99027fd)

Comment: Perhaps I'm a bit confused - but where is the `15` coming from? To what does it correspond? I was pursuing this from a slightly different tack - i.e. you can't have `EPOCH`s over 2^(32 - 1). What's so special about 15?

Comment: The length of "update_date": is 14, so it's to pick first position after that

Comment: Yes - I see now! It doesn't matter how long the string is - your SQL will pick it up no matter what. [Mine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=65b29ce44556476d570a55fe58146817) will eliminate anything that's not a valid EPOCH - but your solution is easily changed to do that also. Plus yours doesn't have the ugly calls to `REVERSE()` **and** no arbitrary 5 character "hop" to obtain the end of the string! I think this should have been the accepted solution - and thanks for having taken the time to explain the logic - upvoted!

Comment: One drawback with my solution is that it cant handle short strings (Ex,  (9, 'WTF')). I tried various ways to filter those out before substring is applied but none worked. There is something I don't understand in the way SQL-server pushes it predicates dow to the base tables. Pauls first query does not have these issues, so I think he deserves the credits

Comment: Hm. more and more (ahem..) interesting. I can modify my solution to work with any string with LEN() >= 1. However, when I use an empty string, TRY_CAST turns it into 0!!! This will work for the OP, but I can see (many) cases where 0 is a valid INT value, but CASTing blank to INT isn't! It's possible to [put a CASE statement in there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=fba8065dc78569da3b6c004845463b5b), but that's **horrible**! :-). This means the "hop" of 3 is no longer arbitrary. It chomps the first char of the string and then gets to the end of it (`"`). So, voilà - solved! :-)